# Create a SAS function that takes as input and output a dataset

Tags: function, input, dataset, sas, output

I am doing the same 10 sub steps transformation to multiple data sets. Let's call this transformation `flag_price_change`.
This transformation takes as an input a dataset and a threshold (real) and creates 10 subdatasets in order to come up with the final one with some added columns. As I said before, I repeat this transformation to multiple datasets

As I am processing multiple data tables the same way, I would like to know if I could create a function like this in SAS.

```
flag_price_change(input_table,column_name1,column_name2,threshold,output_table).
```

Where column_name 1 and 2 are just names of the columns the algorithm just focus on, and output_table should be the created table after the flag_price_change function is executed.

Questions:

1. What's the procedure to define such a function?
2. Can I store it in a separate SAS file?
3. How do I call this function from another SAS program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS functions are for individual observations of data. What you want is a macro (check out a starter guide [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/seminars/sas_macros_introduction/)), which is defined like this:

```
%macro flag_price_change(input_table, column_name1, column_name2, threshold, output_table);
    /** Inside the macro, you can refer to each parameter/argument 
        with an ampersand in front of it. So for example, to add
        column_name1 to column_name2, you would do the following:
    **/

    DATA &output_table;
        set &input_table;

        new_variable = &column_name1 + &column_name2;
    RUN;

%mend;
```

To call the macro, you would do this:

```
%flag_price_change(
    input_table = data1, 
    column_name1 = var1, 
    column_name2 = var2, 
    threshold    = 0.5, 
    output_table = output1);
```

To call the same code on another data set with different variable names and threshold:

```
%flag_price_change(
    input_table = data2, 
    column_name1 = var3, 
    column_name2 = var4, 
    threshold    = 0.25, 
    output_table = output2);
```

There are a lot of tricks and catches with macro programming to be aware of, so do check your work at each step.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful!
What if I place this macro in another SAS program and want to call it? like having a flagalgorithm.sas and myprogram.sas

Comment: Sure, that's very common. Just use %include "flagalgorithm.sas"; at the top of myprogram.sas so that the macro will be compiled and available to use.

Comment: Thanks! Last question... I'm using SAS Entreprise Guide, so my programs are within a project flow under a folder "program". Do you know a way to do %include within Entreprise Guide? Thanks

Comment: If you have access to an autocall library that's assigned as part of your SAS autoexec script, another option is to save the macro there, and then it will automatically be made available to you whenever you start a new session. You can check whether you have one like so `%put %sysfunc(getoption(sasautos));`